# How do I modify my flyback transformer to output 5kV?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, high-voltage, flyback

I was wondering how to modify this circuit to end up with a 5kV power supply. I watched a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGmNRZG-Yg&t=180s) by the Plasma Channel on YouTube on a similar design but it outputs 15-20kV which is too high for my use.

I know it has something to do with the input voltage and the resistors but I'm not sure exactly how I would change them.

[image: Flyback Transformer Driver]

Comment: Start with the DC supply you intend on using. What exactly is it?

Comment: Just decrease the number of secondary turns. The resistors value depends on transistor you are going to use. But generally seems to be ok. Be careful about secondary winding insulation (between layers).

Comment: Note that this is a very, maybe even excessively simple flyback circuit; you could do a lot better with some active control.

Comment: There's a discussion about a 5 kV flyback using a 555 and a TL494 in [*Design and implementation of flyback converter as high voltage power supply for nanofibers production*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matpr.2021.01.857). I've also got a single BJT schematic that is better than the above. I might be able to reconsider some details for 5 kV (was designed for under 1 kV.) The BJT base needs protection, by the way. Also, Schottky HV diodes are 'tricky' to find. (But exist: SiC, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the turns ratio of the transformer to make 5kV output. This transformer structure may different from normal. The bobbin should have several sections to decrease voltage drop.